# Add a Business logic class to another model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been given an assignment that I'm totally stuck on.

I've got two classes:

```
#/app/models/numbers.rb
class Numbers < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Model has(:id, :list_length, :number_list)

  # An array of integers
  serialize :number_list

  #generate the number list
  def create_list
    Array.new(self.list_length).map!{rand(100)}
  end

  def initialize(*params)
    super
    if !params.compact.empty?
      self.number_list = create_list
    end
  end

end
```

and:

```
#/lib/update.rb
class Update
  #takes an array of integers
  def initialize(num_list)
    @num_list = num_list
  end

  def add_rand
    to_add = rand(10)
    @num_list.each{|n| n += to_add}
  end

  def get_list
    @num_list
  end
end
```

So, Update has to remain a library class but I need to be able to instantiate a Numbers object and then call Update class methods on it to update the num_list attribute.

So after creating a Numbers object, let's call it @num_obj, I need to call @num_obj.add_rand and then save the updated @num_obj.num_list array to the database.

I'm allowed to add helpers and modules as I like. After hours and hours of bashing away at this I'm totally lost and I'm sure it's something simple I just haven't learned yet (and probably overlooked in my hours of searching).  Could anybody point me in the right direction?

edit: After more reading and a couple of suggestions, I changed num_list in the Numbers class to numbers_list to make things clearer

I added a module:

```
#/lib/num.rb
module Num
  def add_rand
    temp = Update.new(self.number_list)
    self.number_list = temp.add_rand
  end

  def get_list
    temp = Update.new(self.number_list)
    temp.get_list
  end
end
```

and add 'include Num' to my Numbers class.

Now I can take a Numbers object and call the Update methods on it. 
It works, I'm not sure if there's a more elegant way to do it....

Edit:
Turns out this isn't right, either.  Gotta have Update persist somehow so that get_list method returns Update's num_list

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. You're saying you want to instantiate a `Number` object then call some `Update` class methods, however Update doesn't have any class methods. You mention Update must remain a library class, does this mean you can modify it? Please rephrase your question a bit better so we can understand what it is you need help with. What exactly is the assignment asking you to do?

Comment: `Array.new(self.list_length)!.map{rand(100)}` doesn't compile. You should remove the bang (`!`).

Comment: Also, you must understand that both `num_list`s are different: `Update`s `@num_list` is an instance variable of the class Update entirely different from the `num_list` in `Numbers`. They are *two separate things.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to separate the active record model from how to update it (business logic). You might want to take a look at using something like the [decorator pattern](http://nick-aschenbach.github.io/blog/2016/01/16/video-decorator-design-pattern-in-ruby/):

```
class NumberUpdateDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def add_rand
    number_list.each { |number| number += rand(10) }
    save!
  end
end
```

The usage in code:

```
Numbers.find_each do |number|
  NumberUpdateDecorator.new(number).add_rand
end
```

Also, it might simplify things to change the `Numbers` class to just `Number`. Add a `NumberCollection` model that has many `Number`s. That way you are not dealing with trying to serialize / deserialize the list.